# How to break out of a loop after an input has been checked against every item in an enum Java?

Tags: java, loops, validation, enums, break

I'm trying to make a program that will allow the user to input either a name or symbol of an element from the periodic table, and will then output some data about that element. So far I've managed to get the user to be able to input either a name or a symbol and have it output correctly, but if the user inputs something wrong then the code doesn't output anything, and will stop accepting an input of a symbol and only accept an input of a name. I would like to know how I would be able to break out of the loop and tell a user that their input is invalid only after the input has been checked against every item in the enum, since my current solution doesn't work. I'm new to Java, so a simple explanation as to how and why would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PeriodicTable {

    public enum Element {
        Hydrogen("H", "Nonmetal", "1.008"),
        Helium("He", "Noble Gas", "4.003"),
        Lithium("Li", "Alkali Metal", "6.941"),
        Beryllium("Be", "Alkaline Earth", "9.012"),
        Boron("B", "Semimetal", "10.811"),
        Carbon("C", "Nonmetal", "12.011"),
        //The rest of the periodic table is here, I just removed it for the sake of this post.

        private String symbol;
        private String group;
        private String weight;

        private Element(String symbol, String group, String weight) {
            this.symbol = symbol;
            this.group = group;
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    }

    static Element cName = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int counter = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter the name or symbol of an element in the periodic table. ");
        outer:
        do {
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = reader.nextLine().trim();
            for (Element sy : Element.values()) {
                if (sy.symbol.equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
                    System.out.println("Element: " + sy + " (" + sy.symbol + ")" + "\nGroup: " + sy.group + "\nAtomic Mass: " + sy.weight);
                    reader.close();
                    break outer;
                } else {
                    try {
                        cName = Element.valueOf(input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1).toLowerCase());
                        System.out.println("Element: " + cName + " (" + cName.symbol + ")" + "\nGroup: " + cName.group + "\nAtomic Mass: " + cName.weight);
                        reader.close();
                        break outer;
                    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        if(counter > Element.values().length) {
                            System.out.println("That name or symbol is not valid. Please try again. ");
                            continue outer;
                        } else {
                            counter++;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug and step through the code?  Having that large method is hard to follow - try separating into methods such as `String getNextInput(Scanner reader)`,and `Element getElement(String input)`.  This should help make it easier to simplify the flow and resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using the `valueOf` method in a loop. Instead, you can iterate over the elements and for each element check both its name (use the `name` method) and its symbol.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
outer: while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter the name or symbol of an element in the periodic table. ");
    String input = reader.nextLine().trim();
    for (Element sy : Element.values()) {
        if (sy.symbol.equalsIgnoreCase(input) || sy.name().equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
            System.out.println("Element: " + sy + " (" + sy.symbol + ")" + "\nGroup: " + sy.group + "\nAtomic Mass: " + sy.weight);
            break outer;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("No such element found. ");
}
reader.close(); // this might be a bad idea
```

I would also avoid closing the `reader`, as this will also close `System.in` and you will be unable to read any more input.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question, I would add the logic for parsing `Element`(s) to `Element`. You can create `Map`(s), one to symbol and one of name to corresponding `Element` instances and then invoke them in whichever order you choose. Like,

```
private static Map<String, Element> symbolMap = new HashMap<>();
private static Map<String, Element> nameMap = new HashMap<>();
static {
    for (Element e : Element.values()) {
        symbolMap.put(e.symbol.toUpperCase(), e);
        nameMap.put(e.name().toUpperCase(), e);
    }
}

public static Element fromString(String token) {
    if (symbolMap.containsKey(token.toUpperCase())) {
        return symbolMap.get(token.toUpperCase());
    }
    return nameMap.get(token.toUpperCase());
}
```

Then in `main`

```
Element e = Element.fromString("H"); 
Element e2 = Element.fromString("Hydrogen");
System.out.println(e == e2); // <-- true
```

And if `e` were `null` then it isn't a valid symbol (or name).

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, you want to go through the enums and see if any of the symbols match the user input. If not, print a message and try again. You had the right approach, but in the catch block you don't need to make a counter. Instead if we think through the design, you have `break outer;` if the input ever matches. So the end of the do-while loop will only be reached if there is no matching element. So if we just print a message at the end, this will accomplish our goal:

```
outer:
do {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = reader.nextLine().trim();
    for (Element sy : Element.values()) {
        if (sy.symbol.equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
            System.out.println("Element: " + sy + " (" + sy.symbol + ")" + "\nGroup: " + sy.group + "\nAtomic Mass: " + sy.weight);
            reader.close();
            break outer;
        } else {
            try {
                cName = Element.valueOf(input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1).toLowerCase());
                System.out.println("Element: " + cName + " (" + cName.symbol + ")" + "\nGroup: " + cName.group + "\nAtomic Mass: " + cName.weight);
                reader.close();
                break outer;
            } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Error. No matching elements. Please try again.");
} while (true);
```

***Sample Output:***

```
Enter the name or symbol of an element in the periodic table. 
No
Error. No matching elements. Please try again.
l
Error. No matching elements. Please try again.
He
Element: Helium (He)
Group: Noble Gas
Atomic Mass: 4.003
```

Answer (score 1):

You complicate the code by mixing the search for the name and the search for the symbol.  
 The search for the name does not need to be inside the `for` loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the name or symbol of an element in the periodic table. ");
    boolean found = false;
    do {
        String input = reader.nextLine().trim();

        try {
            cName = Element.valueOf(input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1).toLowerCase());
            System.out.println("Element: " + cName + " (" + cName.symbol + ")" + "\nGroup: " + cName.group + "\nAtomic Mass: " + cName.weight);
            found = true;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        }

        for (Element sy : Element.values()) {
            if (sy.symbol.equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
                found = true;
                System.out.println("Element: " + sy + " (" + sy.symbol + ")" + "\nGroup: " + sy.group + "\nAtomic Mass: " + sy.weight);
            }
        }

        if (!found)
            System.out.println("That name or symbol is not valid. Please try again. ");
    } while (!found);
    reader.close();
}
```